# javafx adding buttons to infinite with function

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8

i am creating a project in which user can create as many program that i have to show as button per program like here i am show a example with `6 program`

[image]

This work is easy in `php` but in `javafx` i don't how to add so many by getting data from database.

**now each button must contain some function**

i can do it manually so there is limit i can't extend it to infinite so i need your help how to do this work.

Comment: You should at least specify how do you know all the programs available and what you've tried to achieve this. TIP: you will probably need a GridPane and a list of the programs/classes to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to accomplish it would be:

1. create a base layer 'pane' (like Kyllopardiun mentioned, probably want a grid from the looks of it)
2. in code, figure out how many buttons you need from the database, probably using JDBC.
3. Using the Pane.getChildren().add() functionality, in a loop, add buttons dynamically to your pane.

Here's an example of this type of functionality:

```
public Class example{

    private Connection createInitialCon() {
        try {
            return DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://yourdatabaseaddress:youdatabaseport/databasename",
                    "database_usernamer",
                    "database_password");
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            rootLog.debug("Error connecting to our database!", e);
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void main(String[] args){
        GridPane main_pane = new GridPane();
        int numberOfButtons = 0;
        Connection con = createInitialCon();
        String line = "";
        try{
            PreparedStatement pstmt; 
            line = "SELECT num_buttons FROM `dbName`.`tableName` WHERE id = \"idOfRow\";"

            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(line);
            pstmt.execute();
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.getResultSet();
            if (rs != null) {
                if (rs.next()) {
                    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
                    for (int i = 1; i < rsmd.getColumnCount() + 1; i++) {
                        switch (rsmd.getColumnType(i)) {
                            case Types.INTEGER: {
                                numberOfButtons = rs.getInt("num_buttons");
                                break;
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Button temp;
            for (int i = 0; i < num_buttons; i++){
                temp = new Button("Button " + i);
                temp.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                        //Do some stuff with the button for this listener. 
                    }
                });
                pane.getChildren().add(temp);
            }

        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

    }


}
```

Obviously this is just an example, and I haven't tested this, it might have some syntax errors here and there, but that's the general idea. You'd also need to add the pane to a scene, and then set the scene to a stage to actually make something show up.

Good luck!